# How can I keep all JQuery in the external script file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some submit buttons with the same ids in multiple views/pages. Currently I keep all my JQuery code in the html view. How can I combine all these JQuery into single JS file. My concern is that I have the button click function like below in multiple pages and they perform different tasks.

I think they gonna have some conflicts not knowing which button click to be called if I put into one JS file. how can i achieve that? I don't like to keep one view/page for one JS file. Thanks.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {

//do something

});
```

Comment: Make the buttons more unique, possibly by giving the views their own class or id that you can use to filter with. Does your submit button really need an id? For that matter, does it even need a click event? use the form submit.

Comment: If you have wrapping `div` you can write like `$('#divId #btnSubmit').click(function() {`.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to load a bunch of (probably) unrelated jQuery code on each view just to consolidate your scripts?

Comment: @KevinB yes I need click event for some reason for ajax call.

Comment: Why does that have anything to do with it? a submit event can send an ajax call.

Comment: If the forms are different enough to have different... submit button events, they're different enough to have different form names or form id's, right?

Comment: @TiesonT. I have some doubts about keeping all JQuery in the HTML view page. I just want to follow some standard way of doing and organizing script. Since i dont want to change and re-name the ids. I gonna keep it like that. hope there is no harm keeping Jquery inline instead of creating external JS file.

Comment: @kyi12321 You can always use a naming scheme like `<<viewname>>.jq.js` if your goal is to simply not have a `<script>` element with all your jQuery code in the view. The only advantage I would think you gain is to make it easier for someone to work on the JavaScript part without needing to worry about markup.

Comment: @TiesonT. yes, that naming scheme might suit my need. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how big your program is, it might be useful to split up your code into their own JS files depending on the page. If you have a registration.php page then you can have a registration.js file that you include. It helps with debugging as well. You then don't need to load a single js file every time that may include 5000 lines of code when really you only need to use a small function.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the forms diffrent Ids.

Then you can use a single external Script like

```
$('#form1').click(function() {

//do something

});

$('#form2').click(function() {

//do something

});
```

You don't need wrapping divs or something like this.

Maybe you can also use `submit()`...

Comment: Then OP has to change the `view` and `js` both.